# How can I automatically change the IP address on each request and when reconnecting in Selenium with Python?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, proxy, rotation

It is necessary to randomly select a proxy with authorization from proxies.txt for **each request**.

It doesn't work as it should...

```
import random
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium_authenticated_proxy import SeleniumAuthenticatedProxy

def parse_proxy(proxy_str):
    parts = proxy_str.split(":")
    ip = parts[0]
    port = parts[1]
    username = parts[2]
    password = parts[3]
    return f"{username}:{password}@{ip}:{port}"

with open("proxies.txt", "r") as f:
    proxies = f.readlines()
    proxies = [parse_proxy(proxy.strip()) for proxy in proxies]

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

for _ in range(1, 4):
    selected_proxy = random.choice(proxies)

    proxy_helper = SeleniumAuthenticatedProxy(proxy_url=f"http://{selected_proxy}")
    proxy_helper.enrich_chrome_options(chrome_options)

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)

    driver.get('https://whoer.net/')

    time.sleep(15)

    driver.quit()
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you detailed what "doesn't work as it should" ? What's your output ?

Comment: @iFlo Thank you for your message.
How to change the IP address with each request in Selenium, for example, when updating a page or clicking on a link?